# $L^p$ compactness for product of two sequences of functions

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lp-spaces

Let $f_n:[a,b] \to \mathbb R$, $n \in \mathbb N$, be a sequence of  $L^p$ functions for some $p \in (1,\infty)$. For every fixed $m\in \mathbb N^*$, suppose that the sequence of functions $$\{f_{n}\psi_m(f_n)\}_{n \in \mathbb N}$$ has a strongly convergent subsequence in $L^p([a,b])$. Here  $\psi_m$ is a smooth function such that
$$\psi_m(f) = 
\begin{cases}
1 \qquad \text{ if } |f|\ge 1/m \\
0 \qquad \text{ if } |f|\le 1/(2m)
\end{cases}
$$
and $0 \le \psi_m \le 1$.

Is it true that $\{f_n\}_{n\in \mathbb N}$ also has a strongly convergent subsequence in $L^p([a,b])$?

---

I wanted to apply a diagonal argument: [[1]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/518062/diagonal-sequence-trick-uniform-bound-necessary), but I can't make it work properly.

Comment: Have you tried the Kolmogorov-Riesz theorem? https://www.math.ntnu.no/conservation/2009/037.pdf

Comment: @OliverDiaz How does that theorem help?

Comment: The argument using diagonal sequence does not work: By assumption, $\{ f_{n} \psi_1 (f_{n})\}$ has a convergent subsequence $\{ f_{n_k} \psi_1( f_{n_k})\}$. But starting at $m=2$, we already do not know if $\{ f_{n_k} \psi_2( f_{n_k})\}$ has a convergent subsequence.

Comment: @ArcticChar Thanks! But I think that if this is the issue we can solve it by a slightly stronger assumption: that the sequence is compact in $L^1$ because it satisfies the assumption of Helly's theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helly%27s_selection_theorem What do you think?

Comment: @ArcticChar In this way you know that also the subsequence $\{f_{n_k}\psi_m(f_{n_k})\}$ has a converging subsequence because it satisfies the same assumption. Also, I'm pretty sure that with this assumption the counterexample below does not hold (because it seems that the cut-off sequence does not have derivatives uniformly bounded with respect to $n$).

Comment: @ArcticChar By the way, I've formulated this in another post: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3776216/deducing-lp-compactness-of-a-sequence-of-functions-from-strong-compactness-pr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There exists a counterexample showing that it is in general not possible to conclude the sequentially compactness of ${f_n}$

Set $[a,b]=[0,1]$ and $p=2$

First, for $k\geq 1$ define $a_k = \sum_{j=1}^k 2^{-j}$

Then, define
$$g_k(x):=2^{k+1} \chi_{[a_{k},a_{k+1}]} (x)$$ .
$$h_{m}(x):=\chi_{[0,1/2]} (x)sin(4\pi m x)$$
Now set
$$f_n(x)=g_{\sigma_1(n)}(x) +  \frac{1}{\sigma_1(n)}h_{\sigma_2(n)}(x) $$
Where $(\sigma_1,\sigma_2): \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N}$ is a bijection.

Then the sequence $\{f_n\}_n$ does not admit convergent subsequences in $L^2[a,b]$. This can be shown using that

1. $$
   \|g_{k_1}+  \frac{1}{k_1}h_{m_1} - (g_{k_2}+  \frac{1}{k_2}h_{m_2})\|_2^2
    = \|g_{k_1} - g_{k_2}\|_2^2 +\|\frac{1}{k_1}h_{m_1} -\frac{1}{k_2}h_{m_2}\|_2^2 
   $$
   since the support of every $g$ is a subset $[1/2,1]$ while the support of every $h$ is a subset of $[0,1/2]$
2. If $k_1 \neq k_2$ $$\|g_{k_1} - g_{k_2}\|_2^2= \|g_{k_1}\|_2^2+ \|g_{k_2}\|_2^2 \geq C$$ where $C$ is a positive constant independent of $k_1,k_2$
3. If $k_1 = k_2$ the term
   $$\|\frac{1}{k_1}h_{m_1} -\frac{1}{k_2}h_{m_2}\|_2^2 = \frac{1}{k_1^2}\| h_{m_1} - h_{m_2}\|_2^2 $$ is equal to zero for $m_1=m_2$ and it is equal to $\frac{1}{2 k_1^2}$ otherwise, using the well known properties of the trigonometric basis.

Nontheless, for every fixed $m$ the family $\{f_{n}\psi_m(f_n)\}_{n \in \mathbb N}$ admits a convergent subsequence.
In fact, the trigonometric term appearing in $f_n$ is cutted off in $f_{n}\psi_m(f_n)$ if $m>\sigma_1(n)$ and therefore if $\{ n_j\} = \{ n \mid \sigma_1(n)=m+1\}$ then subsequence $\{f_{n_j}\psi_m(f_{n_j})\}$ converges to $g_{m+1} \psi_m(g_{m+1})$

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean? What is the counterexample?

Comment: Thanks for the edit. How do you prove that $\{f_n\}_n$ is not compact in $L^2[a,b]$ but, for every fixed $m$, the family $\{f_{n}\psi_m(f_n)\}_{n \in \mathbb N}$ admits a convergent subsequence?

Comment: In particular I think that in your example even $\{f_n \psi_m(f_n)\}$ does not have a subsequence that converges strongly in L^2.

Comment: @zac $\{f_{n}\psi_m(f_n)\}$ admits a convergent subsequence, roughly because one can choose $\sigma_1(n)>m$ fixed, that will kill the second terms. But the same cannot be said for $\{f_n\}$.

Comment: Nice example indeed. I guess the mistake in my answer is when constructing the diagonal sequence. After taking the first subsequence at $m=1$, I cannot use the same subsequence to take further subsequence.

Comment: @ArcticChar Is there an additional assumption that can save the argument in your proof?

Comment: @zac, unless by compact you mean every infinite subset has a limit points? May be that's why FormulaWriter is asking for the definition.

Comment: @ArcticChar I mean that there exists a strongly converging subsequence.

Comment: @zac then my arugment failed when constructing the diagonal sequence (In case you still want to see my wrong answer, I posted that in the sandbox on meta [link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4993/629362)).

Comment: @ArcticChar Thank you! Could you explain again what is the failure in the diagonal construction? Is there any hope or additional assumption that would fix the argument?

Comment: @FormulaWriter Does the counterexample (or another one) hold if I require in addition that $\Vert (f_n\psi_m(f_n))\Vert_{L^1} + \Vert  \partial_x (f_n\psi_m(f_n))\Vert_{L^1} \le C_m$ (where $C_m$ is a constant that depends on $m$ but not on $n$)?

Comment: @Zac I guess it depends on how the $\psi_m$ are defined and if you want the functions $f_n$ to be $C^1$ or simply admitting derivative a.e..

Comment: @FormulaWriter The $\psi_m$ are  smooth functions such that 
$$\psi_m(f) = 
\begin{cases}
1 \qquad \text{ if } |f|\ge 1/m \\
0 \qquad \text{ if } |f|\le 1/(2m)
\end{cases}
$$
and $0 \le \psi_m \le 1$. I could also suppose that the $f_n$ are  $C^1$ (but still $\{f_n\psi_m(f_n)\}$ is assumed to be only compact in $L^p$ with $p < \infty$ and to satisfy the bound with its derivative from my previous comment).

Comment: @Zac In our setting, we have discovered that the question "Is it true that {}∈ℕ also has a strongly convergent subsequence in ([,])?" has an answer: in general it doesn't. Looking for the proper setting for which the answer is yes could be an interesting question. Maybe you should open a new post for it

Comment: @FormulaWriter You're right. I posed this as an additional post: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3776216/deducing-lp-compactness-of-a-sequence-of-functions-from-strong-compactness-pr I'd be very grateful if you could take a look at it.

Comment: @Zac Of course I will :)

Comment: @FormulaWriter Thank you!